# mount points added to the host don't show up in a running docker container

Tags: linux, docker

If I launch a docker container with

```
docker run -v /foo:/foo ...
```

I can see the contents of /foo on the host, from within the container.

While the docker container is running, if I run

```
mount -t ext4 /dev/... /foo/something
```

I will NOT see the new mount point in /foo inside the container - is there any way to make it show up? (if I launch the docker container AFTER the mount point on the host is established, it is ok).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Docker containers run in a private mount namespace, which means that mounts made on the host after the container starts do not propagate into the container.  The [kernel documentation on shared subtrees](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/sharedsubtree.txt) goes into detail about mount propagation and private vs shared vs slave mounts.

The short answer to your question is that there isn't an easy way to expose a new mount like this into a container.  It's *possible*, probably involving the use of `nsenter` to run commands inside the container namespace to change the flags on the mounts, but I wouldn't go there.

In general, if you need to change the storage configuration of a container, you re-deploy the container.

Comment: yep - I had seen the inverse - with mounts inside the container being private - and I can certainly mount on the host with nsenter from within the container if I want... I was surprised that the mount was visible in the container after it was removed from the host. Fascinating stuff! thanks for the answer.

Comment: One legitimate case would be a USB/CD mount on the host being visible in docker - I am surprised I am unable to find similar questions along those lines.